# I need to open a file based on its mime type

Tags: java, types, mime

I have the code to get the mime type. It seems to work. When I put mimeType in an if statement, I don't get the desired effect. Here are the snippets.

GET the mime type--

```
MimetypesFileTypeMap mimeTypesMap = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
String mimeType = mimeTypesMap.getContentType(file);
```

Now I want to only open a file if the mime type is text--

```
if (file.isFile()) {
try {
    if (mimeType == "text/plain") openFile(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.print("    Cannot process file....\n");
}
}
```

This will not open a text file. Any ideas on why it will not work? openFile(file) works and is not the problem. file is a File Object. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to add some tags pointing out which language/technology you are talking about.

Comment: Yes, it is Java. That is why I added the relative tag.

Comment: I'm sorry about not specifying that it is Java code.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing the MIME type using `==`, not `String#equals()` -- it's a String, yes?  You probably have to do this:

```
if (mimeType.equals("text/plain")) openFile(file);
```

Or better still:

```
if ("text/plain".equals(mimeType)) openFile(file);
```

since that prevents a NPE from getting in your way.

Comment: Wow. How dumb am I. I knew that. Been doing some coding in Perl and JS and I did not reset my thinking. Thanks for clearing that up with me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the mime type is just `text`?

> MIME types file search order:
>
> The MimetypesFileTypeMap looks in
>   various places in the user's system
>   for MIME types file entries. When
>   requests are made to search for MIME
>   types in the MimetypesFileTypeMap, it
>   searches MIME types files in the
>   following order:
>
> 1. Programmatically added entries to the MimetypesFileTypeMap instance.
> 2. The file .mime.types in the user's home directory.
> 3. The file /lib/mime.types.
> 4. The file or resource named META-INF/mime.types.
> 5. The file or resource named META-INF/mimetypes.default (usually
>      found only in the activation.jar
>      file).

Find this file and find out what mime type was specified for .txt files. Source: [link](http://www.cs.clemson.edu/~pargas/courses/cs881/spring2002/j2eeapi/javax/activation/MimetypesFileTypeMap.html)

Comment: Unlikely.  For one, `text` isn't a MIME type.  For another, the case for most users is that the fifth item on that list is the one that'll win -- that's the file that's part of the J2EE distribution, and like all MIME type maps, `text/plain` is the type associated with commonly-used text file suffixes.

Comment: The answer you give is not helping me at all. I printed out the mimeType variable and got a mime type for everything I clicked on. (I created a tree using a DefaultMutableTreeNode object and a mouse listener. The JTree code is working.) The String that is printed is text/plain. I can give you the complete code, but it is quite large and my problem is only in this method--

    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent event)

Comment: which I override and is the mouse listener for the JTree. I create a JTree, populate it with DefaultMutableTreeNode's, and when I click on a text file, I want to open it up in a TextArea. I only want to open text files, hence the mime type check. The mime type is being returned properly, I just can't make the file I click on only open if the mime type is the text/plain type. Yes I do check if it is a file and not a directory. Have I explained my dilemma more clearly now? Thanks for your help.

Comment: David, did you see my answer above?  You're not doing your String comparison properly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937903/i-need-to-open-a-file-based-on-its-mime-type/1937993#1937993

Comment: I don't see your point. I am not testing for "text", I am testing for "text/plain", which is what should work, right? It doesn't. I am guessing I can't do that String comparison for some reason.